# Override function in woocommerce.php file inside theme's "inc" folder

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I´ve been trying to search for the answer but I am stuck. I am sorry, I don't know php at all.

Theres is a file in my theme/inc/functions/ folder called woocommerce.php

[Here is a link to the complete code](https://pastebin.com/rUjWs2Tm)

I want to replace this part of the code (from lines 1067 to 1080)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'registration_errors_validation', 10, 3 );

function registration_errors_validation( $reg_errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
global $porto_settings, $woocommerce;
if ( isset( $porto_settings['reg-form-info'] ) && 'full' == $porto_settings['reg-form-info'] && 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) {
    extract( $_POST );
    if ( strcmp( $password, $confirm_password ) !== 0 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'registration-error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'porto' ) );
    }
    return $reg_errors;
}
return $reg_errors;
}
```

With this one:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors', 'registration_errors_validation', 10,3);

function registration_errors_validation($reg_errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
global $porto_settings, $woocommerce;
if( isset( $porto_settings['reg-form-info'] ) && $porto_settings['reg-form-info'] == 'full' && 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ){
    extract( $_POST );
    if ( strcmp( $posted['account_password'], $posted['account_confirm_password'] ) !== 0 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'registration-error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'porto' ) );
    }
    return $reg_errors;
}
return $reg_errors;
}
```

I tried pasting the modified code in the theme's functions.php but i receive a fatal error option saying that cannot redeclare function registration_errors_validation. I also created a child theme with the `inc/functions/` subfolders and copied the modified `woocommerce.php` file there. Finally I also copied the `woocommerce.php` file in the child root folder.
Nothing worked.

I have read something of adding the if( !function_exists() ) at the beginning, but I couldn't solve it myself.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is a filter hook, using your code in a renamed function with a higher priority hook should replace the Porto themes's filtered data… Try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'custom_registration_errors_validation', 20, 3 );
function custom_registration_errors_validation( $reg_errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    global $porto_settings;

    if ( isset( $porto_settings['reg-form-info'] ) && 'full' == $porto_settings['reg-form-info'] && 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) {
        extract( $_POST );
        if ( strcmp( $posted['account_password'], $posted['account_confirm_password'] ) !== 0 ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'registration-error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'porto' ) );
        }
    }
    return $reg_errors;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). This should work.

Comment: LoicTheAztec: Thank you for your answer. Although no fatal error appeared, the code is not working as expected. It does nothing.

Comment: @user3741840 For a filter hook, this is the correct way… Now you might need to define the `$porto_settings` variable as this code runs out of the related plugin and for that I really don't know: **You should better ask Porto's support, opening a thread there**…

Comment: LoicTheAztec: In fact your code works!! I did a very dumb mistake and rushed to answer. I did different tests just to be sure, and then realized it was working. So thank you so much!